# KeyError with a API call

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to get this script work. I want to get a list of synonyms, but i always get the same error "Line 26: KeyError:'term'. Is driving me crazy!

```
import requests
import workflow
import console
import json

term = workflow.get_variable('term')

URL = 'http://openthesaurus.softcatala.org/synonyme/search?q=' + term +  '&format=application/json'

terms = requests.get(URL)

list = []

if terms.status_code == 500:
    console.hud_alert('No Synonyms Found', 'error', 1)
    workflow.stop()

elif terms.status_code == 200:
    console.show_activity('Construint la llista...')

    for element in terms.json()['metaData']['term']:
        list.extend(element['list']['synonyms'].split('|'))

    workflow.set_output('\n'.join(list))
```

Comment: The dict at `terms.json()['metaData']` has no key named 'term' but that should be clear, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You went from checking if the website works (status code 200) to assuming a valid dictionary came back with the elements 'metaData' and 'term'. Bad coding practise. Don't assume anything, especially not if it originates from **ALIEN WORLDS** (internet/clients/etc).

I suggest you make sure those elements exist first before attempting to access them.

```
if 'metaData' in element:
    if 'term' in element['metaData']:
        list.extend(.......)
```

You'll notice 'term' is indeed not in dictionary you fetched.